# DateTime entered from a form rendered as 1969-12-31 19:00:00 when save on database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I used a variation of Amsul datetime picker found at http://jsfiddle.net/amsul/h2V6w/

HTML code

```
    <h3><label for="call_time">Pick a date &amp; time:</label></h3>
    <div id="wrap">
        <input type="text" id="call_time"/>
        <div id="hidden">
            <input type="text" id="date"/>
            <input type="text" id="time"/>
        </div>

        <div id="outlet"></div>
</div>
```

I have this PHP code to get the date and time from the form above

```
<?php
    require("somedatabasedetails.php"); /*** mysql hostname info ***/

    if(isset($_POST['Email'])) 
    {
      try
      {
         // Some other codes here;  I used array here since I deleted other 
         //entries and elements that are working and irrelevant to my question   

         $call_time = $_POST['call_time'];
         $call_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($call_time));

         $que=  "INSERT INTO emailsent(call_time) VALUES (:call_time)"; 

         $query2    = $dbh->prepare($que);

        $results  = $query2->execute(array(
            ":call_time"=>$call_time,
        ));
     }

        catch (PDOException $e)
      {
        $error = 'Error adding elements to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
        echo "Error: " . $error;
        exit();
      }

      exit();
    }
?>
```

On the mysql database, call_time column is formatted as datetime. I tried it also varchar just to test.

My problem is when $call_time is saved on the database it reveals this **1969-12-31 19:00:00**. I have read and tried the queries made in these site, but i cant figure out how to get the user entered datetime and save it with the same datetime format to the database.

What part of the code did I do wrong? Or do i need to change timezone?

thanks from a newbie.

Comment: `varchar` datatype also didnt worked?

Comment: Well, what is the *result* of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($call_time));`? It is *not* what you are expecting.

Comment: I got 1969-12-31 19:00:00 when the value of $call_time is inserted on the database.

Comment: varchar did not work. Actually, when the a user used the datetime form, it will reveal "7 January, 2014 @ 1:00 PM." format which is likely generated by the script. But when sent to database it is inserted as 1969-12-31 19:00:00. try http://jsfiddle.net/amsul/h2V6w/. Thanks for reply

Comment: Set name for all input field in html

Comment: Where is the form ? i did not see any form in your html

Comment: @Awlad Liton: I think your correct. Of all the form fields although not included here, this one is the only one that has a different format (coz i followed the format as sampled on the link). That also explains the error when i used the suggestion of grebneke. How can I get the value then from the form when if used on the browser itself it showed the value on the field as sampled on the link? Thank you so much.

Comment: Now what error you are getting ?

Comment: See my errors as i explained it below to @grebneke. Thanks. I think my html form code may likely be lacking. May be the 'name' or 'for' attributes are lacking or misplaced. What do you think? But how can i have them all work together when the for attribute is dependent to the script?

Comment: @Andy : You should have name attribute for all input field for getting POST data.

Comment: Ok may i know why my question is a duplicate to the one that is linked? My question did not involved conversion into another format but primarily how the current format is saved differently on database. I have read the post beforehand but i knew it is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fix HTML :**

```
<h3><label for="call_time">Pick a date &amp; time:</label></h3>
    <div id="wrap">
        <input type="text" id="call_time" name="call_time"/>
        <div id="hidden">
            <input type="text" id="date"/>
            <input type="text" id="time"/>
        </div>

        <div id="outlet"></div>
</div>
```

It seems that:
Your $_POST['call_time'] has value like this:

```
   6 January, 2014 @ 1:00 AM
```

if so try this:

```
    $call_time =$_POST['call_time'];
    $arr = explode("@", $call_time);
    $call_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($arr[0]));
    $que=  "INSERT INTO emailsent(call_time) VALUES (:call_time)";
    $query2    = $dbh->prepare($que);
    $results  = $query2->execute(array(
        ":call_time"=>$call_time,
    ));
```

If your `$_POST['call_time']` value like this:

```
 6 January, 2014
```

then try your code:

```
     $call_time = $_POST['call_time'];
     $call_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($call_time));

     $que=  "INSERT INTO emailsent(call_time) VALUES (:call_time)"; 

     $query2    = $dbh->prepare($que);

    $results  = $query2->execute(array(
        ":call_time"=>$call_time,
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have learned a lot. I did not however explode @ since it is understandable in the database and when echoed on the website. It teaches me nevertheless another technique.    I noticed however if i used the 2nd one it rendered $call_time null again. It is not the reason I did not used it but it made me wonder why so. But my problem is already solved, i will figure it out later.

Answer (score 1):

Please add a line to check the value before inserting it in the database:

```
...
$call_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($call_time));
// add this and check the output:
var_dump($call_time);
```

Is `$call_time` what you expect it to be at that point?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It shows 2 things: 1. an error stating Undefined index: call_time ...; and 2. at the end of the first error "string '1969-12-31 19:00:00' (length=19). I never expected this.  Can you explain this error?

Comment: Well, you're getting the wrong data from the html form, so it's not a database problem. Now, add a `var_dump($_POST['call_time']);` to see the actual data you're getting from the form. That's where the problem is, most likely.

Comment: Your suggestion helped a lot in identifying some errors i made. I mentioned you in one of my answers above. Now, after using var_dump($_POST['call_time']); aside from the first error I mentioned before i got a NULL. Likely, the third error indicated is the result of undefined call_time; Error adding elements on database. Now, I'm getting somewhere. Thanks. I believe now there is something wrong with my HTML as where I should get the value of call_time.

Comment: I really want to vote up your answer but I am low in reputation. but many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this code

```
<input type="text" name="call_time" id="call_time"/>
```

Comment: This does not work. If you check the link where i derived the html code, its functionality is dependent on some script it was made for. Thank you for the reply though. My main concern is the datetime i derived from the form and saved to the database.

Comment: Sorry I ignored your answer a bit, and thank you very much for it. After using the suggestions of the answers above, I figured your answer is half step in getting the answer i need. After using your code, I was able to get the value from the form and display it. What I just did after was change the column type of call_time in my database into varchar and I worked well. I was hoping though to save it as datetime type, but For now it suffices. Thanks to Awlad Liton and @grebneke.

Comment: May I suggest you edit your answer as i suggested above and i will check it as my accepted answer. Thanks again